# Get web title from ClientContext using URL?

Tags: 2013, javascript

I have the URL of a web (http://intranet/sites/site/web) and I would like to get it's title. I know in PowerShell or C# you could create a Web object from the URL and get the title. Can you do something similar with JavaScript and if so how?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96133/how-to-get-title-and-url-using-allproperties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use (**SP.js**) to Get Web Site Properties like

- Title (`Web.get_title();`).
- Description (`Web.get_description();`).
- Language (`Web.get_language();`).
- UI Version (`Web.get_uiVersion();`).
- Created (`Web.get_created();`).

---

To get `Page Title`, Just add the below code in `Script Editor Web Part` to your page

**[Code]**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWebSite, "sp.js");
});

function retrieveWebSite() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://epm/workflow");
   this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
   clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() + 
      ' Description: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
      '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
} 
</script>
```

Just replace this line

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://epm/workflow");
```

with your site URL

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://intranet/sites/site/web");
```

**Note:** you can get the current site URL as the following:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
```

Check also [Ref: Get Web Site Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410960(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST API to get web Title.
Assuming your web is at url http://intranet/sites/site/myweb
put below link in browser you get be able to see json object.

http://intranet/sites/site/myweb/_api/Web

Json Response.

```
 {
    ......//all other properties.
   "Title": "test",
        "TreeViewEnabled": false,
        "UIVersion": 15,
        "UIVersionConfigurationEnabled": false,
        "Url": "https://fcatcs.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/test",
        "WebTemplate": "STS"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SP 2016 OnPrem:

```
var siteTitle = _spPageContextInfo.webTitle;  // returns name of site
```