# retrieve information from sharepoint pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

Using JavaScript, I need to retrieve from a sharepoint pages. These information

- Title of the pages
- Contents
- images.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**To Get Page Title**

You can use (SP.js) to Get Web Site Properties like Title, Description, Language ....etc.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWebSite, "sp.js");
});

function retrieveWebSite() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://epm/workflow");
   this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
   clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
      '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
} 
</script>
```

For more details check [Get web title from ClientContext using URL?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201961/get-web-title-from-clientcontext-using-url)

---

**To get Page Content**

Use the below endpoint to get the Publishing Page Content.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items(<item id>)?$select=PublishingPageContent
```

For more details check [How to get content of html by using REST service in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117893/how-to-get-content-of-html-by-using-rest-service-in-sharepoint-2013)

---

**To get all images URL in the page**

```
var array = [];
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0, max=images.length; i<max; i++) {
    array.push(images[i].href);
}
```

If you need to get Publishing image field, Check [Retrieve Publishing image field with SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852997/retrieve-publishing-image-field-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-csom)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68469/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-retrieve-information-from-sharepoint-pages).